# Migration via phpmyadmin

Tags: 8, migrations

We are moving to a Drupal distribution. From all the research we have done, there is no easy path to do Drupal 8 to Drupal 8 migration.

We are looking to copy some content via phpmyadmin.

Data we need to move are:

- Taxonomy
- Nodes
- Comments

Which tables do we need to copy from one database to the new?

We did copy the users successfully.

Now wondering if we can do the content as well.

Comment: `there is no easy path to do D8 to D8 migration.` Have you looked at the Migrate API + Migrate Plus module?

Answer (score 0):

if migration sounds too hard ...

install and config
https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content_deploy

then

```
"drush default-content-deploy:entity-list"
```

to see a list then:

```
"drush default-content-deploy:export taxonomy_term"
"drush default-content-deploy:export node"
"drush default-content-deploy:exportcomment"
```

copy the exported files to your next site, make sure the nodes taxonomy_terms and comments have same field structure (can do this by exporting / importing config or look at features module)

after that import your content.

```
   "default-content-deploy:import"
```

again make backups of your "new" database before this though !

extra bonus use version control on the exported content .. that way developers / live sites can share the content easily.